# Recursive function calls working behind the scenes

Tags: c++

So I can't wrap my head around recursive function calls especially with this example:

```
int Addup(int n)
{
    //6
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n + Addup(n - 1);
    /*
    6 + 5 + 4 + 3 + 2 + 1
    */
}
```

Now if for example we did `Addup(6)`, how will that work, what will the program do at runtime? Will it chain all the evaluations after the n then sum them together. I really can't visualize it.

If someone could have a simple way of demonstrating what actually happens at runtime it would be really great.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do it by hand. Write in a paper the current call to `Addup` and the `n` passed to it. You can add a counter, like `Addup_1`, `Addup_2`, `Addup_3` and so on, just to see clear which step in recursion you are. Pay attention on how you use the returned values.

Comment: If you have access a debugger like the one in Visual Studio set a breakpoint in AddUp using the F9 key then inspect the contents of the "Call Stack" window after each time you press F5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The secret to understanding recursion is that recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions.

Your functions work exactly like these:

```
int Addup_1(int n)
{
    return 1;
}

int Addup_2(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n + Addup_1(n - 1);
}

int Addup_3(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n + Addup_2(n - 1);
}

int Addup_4(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n + Addup_3(n - 1);
}

int Addup_5(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n + Addup_4(n - 1);
}

int Addup_6(int n)
{
    if(n <= 1)
        return 1;
    else 
        return n + Addup_5(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: Oh ok thank you, it makes it a bit clearer ,but how does the program do it at runtime with the call?

Comment: Function calls always work the same — an argument is passed to a function, and the function returns a value. If you don't understand recursion, you need to learn how non-recursive functions work first. (I'll add back the argument to make it clearer.)